# Passing user id of current user through a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, partials

I'm trying to pass the id of the user currently signed in into a form rendered by the partial below

```
<%= render :partial=>'new_reservation', :locals=> {:reservation => Reservation.new(:table_id=>@table.id, :user_id=>@user.id)} %>
```

I'm using `Devise` and also tried to call `current_user` but it doesn't seem to be working. Whenever I look at the reservation that was created I don't see a user id.

Any idea what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sending a `new` ActiveRecord object to your partial?

You'd be better setting an instance variable & sending that as a local:

```
#controller
@reservation = Reservation.build(table_id: @table.id, user_id: current_user.id)

#view
<%= render partial: "new_reservation", locals: {reservation: @reservation} %>
```

Comment: It seems locals just works with paritals which must be included